# Add a new column to all existing views

Tags: list-view, column

Is it possible to add a new column to all existing views of a list or I have to do manually for each view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way OOTB using the UI.

So you have to do it manually in the UI or through code (could be PowerShell).

If you create the column in the UI and deselect 'Add to Default View' and then run the following in 'SharePoint 2010 Management Shell':

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint"
$list = $web.GetList("http://sharepoint/Lists/MyList")
$field = $list.Fields["NewColumn"]
0..($list.Views.Count-1) | foreach-object {
  $view = $list.Views[$_];$view.ViewFields.Add($field);$view.Update()
  }
```

Comment: Can please provide a link which explains it?

Comment: Example added. Urls and names should be replaced

Answer (score 1):

You can see the link below, that has a PowerShell 1.0 code to use in SharePoint 2007 environment (that of course can be adjusted to use in SharePoint 2010 environment too)

http://antonioaugusto.com.br/blog/2013/03/19/como-adicionar-uma-nova-coluna-a-todas-as-visualizacoes-de-uma-lista-usando-powershell/